# How to display the view correctly ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**I have a problem displaying the view and I have such a message:**
When starting the https://localhost:44370/Product/Index view should receive a list and receive messages as above where to look for an error

```
Odwołanie do obiektu nie zostało ustawione na wystąpienie obiektu.
Opis: Podczas wykonywania bieżącego żądania sieci Web wystąpił nieobsługiwany wyjątek. Aby uzyskać dodatkowe informacje o błędzie i miejscu jego występowania w kodzie, przejrzyj ślad stosu.

Szczegóły wyjątku: System.NullReferenceException: Odwołanie do obiektu nie zostało ustawione na wystąpienie obiektu.

Błąd źródła:


Wiersz 24:     </tr>
Wiersz 25: 
Wiersz 26: @foreach (var item in Model) - it is marked in red {
Wiersz 27:     <tr>
Wiersz 28:         <td>

Plik źródłowy: E:\Visual\Shop\Shop\Views\Product\Index.cshtml    Wiersz: 26
```

When starting the https: // localhost: 44370 / Product / Index view
should receive a list and receive messages as above where to look for an error

**This my View:**

```
 @model IEnumerable<Shop.Models.Product>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

This is controller:

```
    using Shop.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Shop.Controllers
    {
        public class ProductController : Controller
        {
            static List<Product> _products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product {Id = 1, Name = "Myszka", Description = "Opis myszki", Price = 500},
                new Product {Id = 2, Name = "Klawiatura", Description = "Opis klawiatury", Price = 600},
                new Product {Id = 3, Name = "Słuchawki", Description = "Opis słuchawki", Price = 1500},
                new Product {Id = 4, Name = "Monitor", Description = "Opis myszki", Price = 2500}
            };


            // GET: Product
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var model = _products;
                return View();
            }

            // GET: Product/Details/5
            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                var model = _products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
                if (model == null)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                return View();
            }

            // GET: Product/Create
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }

            // POST: Product/Create
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(Product collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add insert logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            // GET: Product/Edit/5
            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // POST: Product/Edit/5
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(int id, Product collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add update logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            // GET: Product/Delete/5
            public ActionResult Delete(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // POST: Product/Delete/5
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Delete(int id, Product collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add delete logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Specifically, `Model` in your view is `null` because you're not sending a model instance to the view.  `return View()` sends no model.  `return View(model)` does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the model to the view. When you don't pass the model into the view from the controller, the `Model` in the view is set to `null`. Then, when you want to execute the `foreach`, basically you are trying to invoke a method on a null object, hence the exception

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _products;
    return View(model);
}
```